# I couldn't find a .sln file in my directory so how to open my project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to run my group project but when I try to open project folder, it shows an empty folder.

How to import my project?

Folder contents:

[image]

Comment: Use `File > Open >  Web Site` and then just navigate to that folder ....

Comment: This is a  classic ASP so you need to open it as website

Comment: Thanks @marc_s its working

Answer (score 3):

Open your project as website.

`Open VS` -> `Go to` -> `File` -> `Open Website (Shift+Alt+O)` -> select Your parent directory of your project (web site)

see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) wonderful article of MSDN

Comment: I opend as WEB PROJECT

Answer (score 1):

First **Enable Show hidden files in folder option** . In your solution folder you must have a folder named **.vs** in this folder you can find your solution file (*.sln). Copy that to your solution folder .

If not found

You must manually add all projects to new Solution

- in Visual Studio.  Go to **file** -> **New Project**
- Then go to **Other Project Types** -> **Visual Studio Solutions** , You should see **Blank Solution**
- create a blank solution.
- right click on the solution and go to **Add** -> **Existing Project** and select your projects.

Comment: hey i oped as a web project

Comment: This won't work as there is no project file, it's a classic website

Answer (score 0):

You can open your project with the .csproj file, this file name is same as your project name. [YourProjectName.csproj]

Now in Visual Studio.NET 2017, you can use Open Folder to open it.

or

Create a blank or other solution and add the existing project.

or

Create a new classic web application with the **same name and namespace** then copy this project files on new project folder, and on the visual studio in **Project** menu click on Show All Files and then select new files in solution explorer and right click on then **Include In Project** and use it.

Comment: Sadly, it is a classic website and there is no .csproj file

Comment: hey i oped as a web project